# How to unmerge a wireless connection in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Recently got a windows 7 desktop, and bought a ZENDnet USB wireless n adapter for it. Installed the software. Worked fine, but began to have some issues. Notably that there was a listed `Wireless Connection` and `Wireless Connection 2`. Going back and forth with trying to fix the competition both connections were having (although there is only 1 wireless adapter - the desktop does not have a built in one) I managed to merge the two. It seemed like the right thing to try at the time but now I am not so sure. Moreover, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to unmerge them. I read that there should be a link `Customize` inside of the Network and Sharing Center but there does not seem to be one. Now, all I see in the view for Network Connections is the normal wired connection, a Wireless Connection #2, and that is it. I know there is a `Wireless Connection` in there because I merged it.

How can I unmerge `Wireless Connection #2` into what should be `Wireless Connection` and `Wireless Connection #2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System restore was the only solution.

However, this did not fix the original issue which was a duplicate network showing up. I did manage to solve this issue by doing this:

run cmd.exe with administrative rights and input:

ROUTE DELETE 0.0.0.0

### edit

What was actually happening had nothing to do with windows 7 in this instance. There were in fact two connections and that is why two were showing up. The issue was related to the way that a routing path was set up. The internet connection to the computer went through an outside router, then an inside one.  The outside router was configured to automatically assign ip addresses as a typical router should (DHCP). The problem stemmed specifically from the fact that the inside router was also setup to assign ip addresses. This was causing a conflict in which IP address was assigned. It was simply fixed turning off DHCP from the inside router, and changing its settings to be a gateway instead of a router.

Answer (score 2):

1) At " Network and Sharing Center " click on the network icon, at the popped up window click on " Merge or delete network location" .  There you should see your network's status as "in use". Leave that window opened.

2) Go to " Network and Sharing Center" -> "Change Adapter Settings". Disable  all the network adapters that are joined into your network.

3) Switch back to the " Merge or delete network location" window. Now your network's status should be displayed as "Not in use" (and when selecting that network delete button is active). Delete the network.

4) Now you can enable the network adapters that you've disabled in step 2 and it should guide you through creating new networks for each network adapter.

Comment: This is a proper approach, however, the issue would keep occurring even after taking those steps because of an external problem. See my edit above for more information.